# How can I create two seperate lists and display them?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am making a team picker for a game and what I need to do is make it so each team has an equal amount of players and if the drop-down value box next to the person's name is the same as another person, they will be on different teams automatically. At the end, I need it to display the two teams.

I have been trying to use the "=" for the dropdown and provide two different events based on whether things equal each other

Here is the JavaScript I have been using. The function on the bottom is not complete because what needs to happen is it search all the players for matching tags and separate them. Here is the code:

```
var teamgreen = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
var teamblue = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
var no1 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer1').value;
var no2 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer2').value;
var no3 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer3').value;
var no4 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer4').value;
var no5 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer5').value;
var no6 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer6').value;
var no7 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer7').value;
var no8 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer8').value;
var no9 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer9').value;
var no10 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer10').value;
var no11 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer11').value;
var no12 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer12').value;
var no13 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer13').value;
var no14 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer14').value;
var no15 = document.getElementById('nosameteamplayer15').value;
Function; makeFunction(); {
  if (no1 === no2) {
teamgreen[0] = document.getElementById('player1nametext').text;
teamblue[0] = document.getElementById('player2nametext').text;
} else {
teamgreen[0] = document.getElementById('player1nametext').text;
teamgreen[0] = document.getElementById('player2nametext').text;        
}
}
```

The `nosameteamplayer` ids are dropdowns with letters and the html for the dropdown is below:

````
<select id="nosameteamplayer1" name="nosameteamplayer1">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
</select>```
````

Comment: `drop-down value box next to the person's name is the same as another person`? What does that mean?

Comment: If the dropdown is the same letter then they will autmatically be seperated

Comment: But with what are your comparing?

Comment: If the letters are the same, one person will go to one team and the other person will go to the other team.